# How to access Android image resources (Eclipse)

Tags: android, android-resources

I'm coding a card game for Android, so I have 40 card images, in 4 different densities, distributed into res/drawable-ldpi, hdpi, mdpi and xhdpi.

I have defined my Card class with a Rect region among its members, where I'm going to print a different image for each card. Code is:

```
package Maze;

import android.R;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Rect;

public class Card {
    private CardNumber number;
    private CardSuit suit;
    private Rect region;
    private boolean visible;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private Bitmap backsideImg;

    public Card(CardNumber number, CardSuit suit){
        this.number = number;
        this.suit = suit;
        this.visible = false;
        region = new Rect();
        setBitmap();
    }

    private void setBitmap(){
        backsideImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(R.drawable.reverse);
        if(suit==CardSuit.HEARTS){
            switch(number){
            case ONE:
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(R.drawable.onehearts); // For onehearts.png file
                break;
            case TWO:
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(R.drawable.twohearts); // For twohearts.png file
                break;
            case THREE:
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(R.drawable.threehearts);
                break;
            case CUATRO:
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(R.drawable.fourhearts);
                break;
            // And so on...

            }
        }

    }

    public void draw(Canvas c, int x, int y){
        region.left = x;
        region.top = y;
        region.right = x + 80;
        region.bottom = y + 115;

        if(visible) c.drawBitmap(bitmap, x, y, null);
        else c.drawBitmap(backsideImg, x, y, null);

    }
}
```

But it is not finding the resources. It says for example "1hearts cannot be resolved or is not a field". I guess I'm missing some step, I just dragged and dropped the images to the resource folders.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename your file names to start with a letter. The autogenerated `R.drawable` fields are named the same as your file names, but have to be valid Java identifiers.

**Edit:**

Also, check that you are including the right `R` class. You might want to update your question with the full content of the `Card.java`, not just the class code.

**Edit 2:**

As I suspected, you are importing `android.R`, which is the system resources class. You should be using the `R` class generated from your resources instead. Given your package name, I'd expect it to be `Maze.R`.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that, but anyway I have files like kinghearts.png which are named correctly and are giving the same error. So I must be missing something else...

Comment: Ok, done. As you can see, I'm importing android.R. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use decodeResource and not decodeFile

Something like:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.oneOfHearts);
```

Comment: What is the difference? And what is getResources() method?

Comment: I just realise you create your bitmap in a card class and not an activity. The getResources() is a static member of Context.